# Google Maps Street View Not Always Loading - How to Make it Fail Gracefully

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps

I'm trying to use a Google Maps Street View as a background using a simple iframe embed that's set in CSS to 100% height and width.

Works fine... some of the time.

Sometimes though, the Google Map fails and I'm left with a gray background from the Google Street View iframe embed. It looks like Street View is Flash-based, while the regular map view is not. Not sure if that's part of the problem.

But basically, I was hoping that if the street view failed, I could instead have a static image fallback. But I'm not seeing a systematic way to determine whether it failed to load. Visually, it's obvious, but not seeing Flash or the JS throwing an error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you just using the embedded script for a location of street views? If so that is just an iframe. I don't know that you can set something to detect whether the app fails to load within the frame and then display an image or link if it fails to load. The answer to this probably lies in the maps API somewhere if a work around for a failure to load the maps exist.

Comment: Yes, currently, it's just an embedded iFrame. API is kind of what we're leaning towards for more options, control, etc.

Comment: I would get comfortable with the javascript or flash API, because you can set some basic backgrounds and such for a iframe so if it failed to load you could see the background image/color. However the frame from google could be loading just fine and the maps don't initialize correctly so you have a dead app but it is over the background so you still can't see it. This is a hard thing to solve without knowing the reason it is crashing, even at that you have a lot of variables to take into consideration so it is probably best to use the API and ask around on the API forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could always use a static gmap fallback: place the img in the same container your gmap is and just place it underneath. you get double bonus cause its good for SEO and Accessibility. http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/  i blogged about this as well here: http://bowdenweb.com/wp/2011/05/optimize-google-maps.html